# Using Server.MapPath() inside a static field in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static, lucene.net, server.mappath

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC site where I'm using Lucene.Net for search queries. I [asked a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480974/proper-structuring-of-lucene-net-usage-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site) about how to properly structure Lucene.Net usage in an ASP.NET MVC application and was told that the best method is to declare the my `IndexWriter` as `public static`, so that it can be re-used.

Here is some code that is at the top of my SearchController:

```
public static string IndexLocation = Server.MapPath("~/lucene");
public static Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer();
public static IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(IndexLocation,analyzer);
```

As `writer` is static, `IndexLocation` must also be static. Thus, the compiler is giving me the following error for `Server.MapPath()`:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Server.get'

Is there **a way of using Server.MapPath() or something similar from a static field**? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Try [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx), which is `static`.

See this SO question for confirmation that `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` returns the same value as `Server.MapPath`:  [What is the difference between Server.MapPath and HostingEnvironment.MapPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944219/what-is-the-difference-between-server-mappath-and-hostingenvironment-mappath)

Comment: This function gave me an error as the result returbed by HostingEnvironment.MapPath is not the same as Server.MapPath, the latter returns an absolute url not a relative url

Comment: @john, I get the same value for both.

Answer (score 56):

I think you can try this for calling in from a class

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SignatureImages/");
```

**----------------Sorry I oversight, for static function already answered the question* by adrift*

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/SignatureImages/");
```

**Update**

I got exception while using     `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/SignatureImages/");`

Ex details :  System.ArgumentException: The relative virtual path 'SignatureImages' is not allowed here. at System.Web.VirtualPath.FailIfRelativePath()

**Solution (tested in static webmethod)**

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SignatureImages/");`    **Worked**

Comment: The only time I saw the error you mentioned in your update is when the code used a relative virtual path.  For example, `Server.MapPath()` allows a path of "files/file1.doc".  It uses the current context to determine the path of the current page, for example, and then creates the relative path from there.  If we are in `~/Subfolder/Page1.aspx`, the url would map from `~/Subfolder/files/file1.doc`.  The `HostingEnviornment.MapPath()` is static, and thus always requires the full virtual path, starting with the `~/` part of the url.