# Full-text search on the site with static content. Lucene.net vs elasticsearch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, lucene.net

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC site with static content (without DB) where I am going implement full text search.

I can use two tools for it:

1. Lucene.Net
2. [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

I started to investigate Lucene.Net but I can`t find an ASP.NET MVC example for it.

I found how to use it in [ASP.NET](http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx).
[Proper structuring of Lucene.Net usage in an ASP.NET MVC site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480974/proper-structuring-of-lucene-net-usage-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site)

My questions is: What is the best choice for ASP.NET MVC application and has good documentation/examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My point of view elasticsearch would be simple choice.

[Extending MVCMusicStore with Elastic Search](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/extending-aspnet-mvc-music-store-with-elasticsearch)

A code project article on [Lucene on MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms)

A [Simple tips from a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480974/proper-structuring-of-lucene-net-usage-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site)

This is a [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641574/lucene-net-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

Another line on similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lucene.net?sort=frequent).

Comment: A have read article on Lucene on MVC. But they use a documents from somewhere to fill the site. I would like to use site URL to index the site context.

Comment: Yes, i feel the same. I have issues on implementing lucene too..We gotta work on our own..once you finished write a damn article :P